# Setstate provided by the context is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Visualizer from './components/Visualizer/Visualizer';
import ArrayProvider from './contexts/arrayProvider';

function App() {
  return (
    <ArrayProvider>
      <Visualizer />
    </ArrayProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Visualizer.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import MenuBar from '../MenuBar/MenuBar'
import { useArray } from '../../contexts/arrayProvider'

import './Visualizer.min.css'
import { resetArray } from '../../utils/helpers'

function Visualizer() {
    const { array, setArray } = useArray()

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Visualizer mounted!")
        setArray(resetArray(array))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="visualizer">
            <MenuBar />
            {array.map((num, idx) => <div key={idx}>{idx}: {num} </div>)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Visualizer;
```

arrayProvider.tsx

```
import React, { useContext, createContext, useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";
import { ARRAY_LENGTH, generateArray } from "../utils/helpers";

export interface IFC_ProviderProps {
    children?: any
}

type ArrayContextData = number[]
type ArrayContextValue = {
    array: ArrayContextData;
    setArray: Dispatch<SetStateAction<ArrayContextData>>;
}

export const ArrayContext = createContext<ArrayContextValue | undefined>(undefined)

const ArrayProvider = (props: IFC_ProviderProps) => {
    const [array, setArray] = useState(generateArray(ARRAY_LENGTH))

    return (
        <ArrayContext.Provider value={{ array, setArray }}>
            {props.children}
        </ArrayContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useArray = () => {
    const ctxValue = useContext(ArrayContext)
    if (ctxValue === undefined) throw new Error(
        "Expected an AppProvider somewhere in the react tree to set context value")
    return ctxValue // now has type AppContextValue
    // or even provide domain methods for better encapsulation
}

export default ArrayProvider
```

MenuBar.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useArray } from '../../contexts/arrayProvider'
import { resetArray } from '../../utils/helpers'

import './MenuBar.min.css'

export default function MenuBar() {
    const { array, setArray } = useArray()

    console.log("Rendering Menubar")

    const generateNewArray = () => {
        console.log("Generating...")
        setArray(resetArray(array))
    }

    return (
        <div className="menu-bar">
            <button
                className="generate-new-array-btn"
                onClick={generateNewArray}
            >Generate New Array</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am trying to create a sorting visualizer. I am using context API to provide the array to several components. The generate new array button inside menubar randomizes the array.

The problem is that when I click the generate-array button, it does randomize the array, but the `setArray` method doesn't update the state.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are saying that `setArray(resetArray(array))` isn't actually updating the state? Can you share this `resetArray` utility?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you modify array in place and reference to object stays same, so React can't know that you updated it.

Try it, if it works you need to modify *resetArray* helper to return a new array

```
const generateNewArray = () => {
    console.log("Generating...")
    setArray([...resetArray(array)])
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `setArray(resetArray([...array]))` or `setArray(resetArray(array.slice()))`?

Comment: setArray(resetArray([...array]))  this should works too

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suspect you are simply mutating the current state object and not returning new references via this `resetArray` utility.

Since updating states that *are* arrays, or contains arrays, you will typically want to use a functional state update to update from the previous state and not just whatever state may be closed over in callback scope.

```
setArray(array => resetArray(array));
```

You will want to also ensure your `resetArray` utility isn't mutating what is passed to it. With React state updates you generally make shallow copies of state that you are updating, that same goes for utility functions where you are avoiding mutations. In your `resetArray` utility you will want to first shallow copy the passed array argument ***and then*** apply any resetting logic.

```
const resetArray = array => {
  const nextArray = array.slice();

  // ... apply resetting logic against nextArray

  return nextArray;
};
```

If the `array` state value matches the function signature of `resetArray` (i.e. same arg number and types match) then you can directly pass the `resetArray` function and avoid the anonymous function.

```
    setArray(resetArray);
```